# Does JBoss only deploy files with the right extension?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a very simple question: what are the deployment requirements for a file under the deployment folders (lib folders, deploy.last) in JBoss? Does JBoss look at the extension and if it's not `.jar`, `.ear`, `.war`, `.sar`... doesn't deploy it? Or will it identify as such a JAR file (for instance) with another extension? If the latter, which extensions are concerned?

I am asking about JBoss en general but just in case, my version is 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible list of deployers can be found [here](https://thenewcircle.com/static/bookshelf/jboss_admin_tutorial/deploying.html) under 6.4.1. TYPE OF DEPLOYERS